# Excel VBA: How to show picture from comment inside of UserForm?

Tags: excel, image, comments, userform

I have a column. Each row in the column has a picture inside of a comment.

How could I show the picture from the comment, inside of a UserForm?

If I can't do it with a userform, is there an alternative approach?

Comment: Huh, interesting question... I'm gonna give you a really crappy answer here and say "You can't with VBA". I thought you could *maybe* get it with `Range().Comment.Shape.CopyPicture`, but for whatever reason that doesn't capture much of anything. I don't think it's possible imo.

Comment: If you're feeling adventurous you could save a copy of the workbook, unzip it, and parse through the xml to find the name of the comment image - you can then grab that from the `\xl\media\` folder in the unzipped version of the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using the clipboard and some API's this will get you started
(Needs an Image control on the UserForm and a Comment with a background picture in the 'A1' cell). No error handling included. Drop it in your UserForm code.

```
Const CF_BITMAP = 2
Const IMAGE_BITMAP = 0
Const LR_COPYRETURNORG = &H4

Private Type uPicDesc
    Size As Long
    Type As Long
    hPic As Long
    hPal As Long
End Type

Private Type GUID
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type


#If Win64 = 1 And VBA7 = 1 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CopyImage Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal un1 As Long, ByVal n1 As Long, ByVal n2 As Long, ByVal un2 As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "oleaut32.dll" (PicDesc As uPicDesc, RefIID As GUID, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As Long, iPic As IPicture) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long
    Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function CopyImage Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal un1 As Long, ByVal n1 As Long, ByVal n2 As Long, ByVal un2 As Long) As Long '
    Private Declare Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "oleaut32.dll" (PicDesc As uPicDesc, RefIID As GUID, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As Long, iPic As IPicture) As Long
#End If


Private Function DefinePicture(ByVal hPic As Long, ByVal hPal As Long) As IPicture
    Dim pInfo As uPicDesc, pGUID As GUID, iPic As IPicture
    Const PICTYPE_BITMAP = 1
    With pGUID
        .Data1 = &H7BF80980
        .Data2 = &HBF32
        .Data3 = &H101A
        .Data4(0) = &H8B: .Data4(1) = &HBB: .Data4(2) = 0: .Data4(3) = &HAA: .Data4(4) = 0: .Data4(5) = &H30: .Data4(6) = &HC: .Data4(7) = &HAB
    End With
    With pInfo
        .Size = Len(pInfo)
        .Type = PICTYPE_BITMAP
        .hPic = hPic
        .hPal = hPal
    End With
    OleCreatePictureIndirect pInfo, pGUID, True, iPic
    Set DefinePicture = iPic
End Function

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
   With Range("A1").Comment
        .Visible = True
        .Shape.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
        .Visible = False
    End With
    OpenClipboard 0&
    Image1.Picture = DefinePicture(CopyImage(GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_COPYRETURNORG), 0)
    CloseClipboard
End Sub
```